# redirecting records in file which matches particular value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have one file and i want to cut all records within file from 67th to 69th position which matches with "926" and 179th 182nd position which matches with "0044".How to achieve this.Could any one help me please?

Comment: post your sample data

Comment: let suppose my file records looks like MM 000000111 ttthhh 776.And i want to extract all those records where 10-12 position 111 and 21 to 23rd position 776 is there.

Answer (score 2):

> `i want to extract all those records where 10-12 position 111 and 21 to 23rd position 776 is there.`

You can do this via awk:

```
awk 'substr($0, 10, 3) == "111" && substr($0, 21, 3) == "776"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` for the example in the comment:

```
grep '.\{9\}111.\{8\}776' input
```

For the original question:

```
grep '.\{66\}926.\{112\}0044' input
```

Somewhat easier way, so that you don't need to do the subtraction:

```
grep '.\{66\}926' | grep '.\{178\}0044' input
```